# Struggling with log4j: simple file appender not working

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have a maven project (A) that uses another maven project (B) and I want to set up logging in A to specifically log me message from one package in B.

My log4.properties I use in A looks like this (I want sysout and file logging):

```
### direct log messages to stdout ###
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

### direct messages to file console.log ###
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${user.home}/Desktop/log.txt
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

### set log levels - for more verbose logging change 'info' to 'debug' ###

log4j.rootLogger=debug,file,stdout
log4j.logger.myutils.twitterUtils=info
```

The myutils.twitterUtils packages contains the classes I want to log. Unfortunately, the log file I create remains entirely empty and nothing is logged at all. The cyst logging works for unknown reason. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: is twitterUtils a package or a class?

Comment: It is a package, sorry for the confusion. I corrected it.

Comment: since you are using Maven, please add the relevant pom.xml snippet of how you reference the log4j library/dependency. is the log4j.properties file placed in "src/main/resources" of module A? it should be...